# Not able to install a python package from my old python version

Tags: python

I am using old version of python (2.6)

```
$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
```

I want to install module Fabric
installing from behind the proxy

```
$ sudo pip install Fabric==1.13.1 --proxy <proxy>
```

getting error like

```
Downloading Fabric-1.13.1-py2-none-any.whl (92kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 141kB/s
Collecting paramiko<3.0,>=1.10 (from Fabric==1.13.1)
Using cached paramiko-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.7 (from paramiko<3.0,>=1.10->Fabric==1.13.1)
Using cached pyasn1-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting bcrypt>=3.1.3 (from paramiko<3.0,>=1.10->Fabric==1.13.1)
Using cached bcrypt-3.1.4-cp26-cp26mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting cryptography>=1.5 (from paramiko<3.0,>=1.10->Fabric==1.13.1)
Using cached cryptography-2.1.4.tar.gz
Collecting pynacl>=1.0.1 (from paramiko<3.0,>=1.10->Fabric==1.13.1)
Using cached PyNaCl-1.2.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'cffi' (maybe misspelled?)
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for cffi>=1.4.1
```

it was working previously (1 year back)
I can not upgrade python due to legacy issue.
Looks like it is deprecated.

need your help to resolve this.

Comment: It's probably problem with your proxy. Both https://pypi.python.org/simple/fabric/ and https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/ is available in proper version. Can you check if you can install any other packages?

Comment: yeah i can install other packet..

Comment: now what i did is copied the package folder from a working server to this server..  from python prompt when i try to import fabric it is happening fine.. but when i run the code it fails again..

Comment: Using cached Fabric-1.9.1-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting paramiko>=1.10 (from fabric==1.9.1)
  Using cached paramiko-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.7 (from paramiko>=1.10->fabric==1.9.1)
  Using cached pyasn1-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting bcrypt>=3.1.3 (from paramiko>=1.10->fabric==1.9.1)
  Using cached bcrypt-3.1.4-cp26-cp26mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting cryptography>=1.5 (from paramiko>=1.10->fabric==1.9.1)
  Using cached cryptography-2.1.4.tar.gz
Collecting pynacl>=1.0.1 (from paramiko>=1.10->fabric==1.9.1)
  Using cached PyNaCl-1.2.1.tar.gz

Comment: i tried to install each of the individually.. all installed but on trying to install cryptography I got error "build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/_openssl.c:35074: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token" .....

Comment: Which system are you using? It's RHEL 6? Do you have openss-devel installed?

Comment: It is Oracle Linux. yeah it is installed

Comment: $ rpm -qa | grep openss
openssl-devel-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.8.x86_64
openssh-askpass-5.3p1-104.el6_6.1.x86_64
openssh-clients-5.3p1-104.el6_6.1.x86_64
openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.8.x86_64
openssh-5.3p1-104.el6_6.1.x86_64
openssl098e-0.9.8e-18.0.1.el6_5.2.x86_64
openssh-server-5.3p1-104.el6_6.1.x86_64